# unable to load variable value in jenkins build

Tags: jenkins

ok  i have situation my in  current  jenkins build.
Build steps are like this

```
sh new_script.sh $USER
helm package $USER
container_name=`helm install $USER-0.1.0.tgz | grep ContainerCreating | awk '{print $1}'`
echo "$container_name"
password=`openssl rand -base64 14`
echo -e "$password\n$password" |  kubectl exec -i $container_name -- passwd
```

but when i run this job, it fails to load the variable `container_name` value.
How can we resolve this
[image]

Comment: The `grep` is obviously not finding the string `ContainerCreating` in the output from `helm install`.  You should run that `helm` command and check what it's actually outputting.

Comment: @Kusalananda  : u were right! i rectified  that! there was some issue with environment! now there is a new issue!  i have updated the snapshot again!

Comment: I don't know about the actual error that you now get, but if `passwd` is the standard `passwd` program to change a password (the root password in this instance), I'd be surprised if it was able to read the password from its standard input. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714915/using-the-passwd-command-from-within-a-shell-script